# Keeping model records and associated directories in sync (with tests)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, filesystems

In my app I create a directory when I create my theme record. This is to store file assets related to the theme. I've always struggled with how to keep the existence of the directory in sync with the lifecycle of the record. This is my current take:

```
after_create :create_theme_directory
after_rollback :destroy_theme_directory, :on => :create, :if => :id

def directory
    Rails.configuration.uploads_root.join('themes', id.to_s)
end

private

def create_theme_directory
    FileUtils.mkdir_p directory
end

def destroy_theme_directory
    FileUtils.remove_dir directory, :force => true
end
```

It works well except that Rspec doesn't seem to trigger the removal of the directory when it rolls back theme records after tests.

Is there a best practice for this kind of thing? The idea being that one should never be left with a stray directory without an associated record.

Comment: There may be a better way, but you could use after(:all) to explicitly call destroy theme directory for the objects created.

Comment: That's true. The problem is that my initial database seed contains a theme so I'd have to selectively delete the rest. I guess it's ok as long as I can predict the ID of that particular initial theme (probably 1!).

Comment: are you using a `before(:all)`? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I'd use that for. What are you thinking? :)

Comment: Oh I get it, I'm using factory_girl to create the themes so they're within the transaction that gets rolled back. I think it's just that the rollback isn't called via rails so rails doesn't know to trigger the callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `after_rollback` callback you have defined will only get called if the creating, destroying or updating a record were done through ActiveRecord. When RSpec resets, it doesn't go through ActiveRecord so it doesn't trigger any of the transaction callbacks (after_rollback and after_commit).

You could add another callback that destroys the directory if it still exists:

```
after_commit :destroy_theme_directory, :on => :destroy

def destroy_theme_directory
  if File.directory?(directory)
    FileUtils.remove_dir directory, :force => true
  end
end
```

And then trigger both the create and destroy actions in your feature spec:

```
scenario 'create and destroy' do
  visit new_directory_path
  #fill_in fields
  click_button "Create"

  expect(page).to have_content "created"

  visit users_path
  click_link "Delete" #assuming only directory object exists and you have a delete link in your directory index page
end
```

In this way, you trigger both the create and destroy actions in your specs so you don't need to do any clean-up.

The other option is to manually remove the directory in the spec where you test its creation.

```
#assuming you have model spec for testing that directory is created
it 'creates corresponding directory'
  directory.create
  expect(File.directory?(directory)).to eq true

  # the line below is just for cleanup. No need to do it in an after_all block if it only needs to be done for a few specs
  FileUtils.remove_dir directory, :force => true 
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this is that if the destroy fails (in the database) the directory will already be deleted. Not necessarily a bad thing, but it breaks the consistency. It's less likely that the directory removal will fail so that's why I'd run it once I know for sure the database entry is gone.

Comment: That makes sense. Is your spec where you test the creation of the directory a feature/request or model spec? By the way, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gjaldon, Your answer is great in that it describes what's going on exactly. I'll award you the points :) The testing of the directory creation happens in the model specs but directories also get incidentally made anywhere I test themes. There could be a way to manually trigger the callbacks via active record perhaps. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting question for which I have an interest of my own since I am currently developing an application where files are being uploaded and converted.

Not an expert on RSpec at all, but I suppose it is very much database orientated and leaves it up to the user to clean up after himself if it's not related to the database (like creation of folders/updating images/initiating an external interface).

Found this example on how to use after(:all) for the cleanup [with RSepc and carrierwave testing](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Cleanup-after-your-Rspec-tests) - similar to my initial though.

Another alternative is more pragmatic and probably more limited when it comes to testing.
Have a backup file for your target structure available and restore it after tests have been completed.

I am indeed interested if anyone has a better method.

Hope this helps!
Eugen

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm hoping that there might be a way for rails to acknowledge the rollback call by rspec and perform the callbacks. I guess normally an error gets raised and rails handles the rollback (calling the callbacks) but rspec is just manually calling that on the database instead (bypassing rails).